# How to make Pylance understand Pydantic's `allow_population_by_field_name` for initializers?

Tags: python, pydantic, pylance

In my current project, we are using an OpenAPI-to-TypeScript-API generator, that generates automatically typed functions for calling API endpoints via Axios. In Python, we use `snake_case` for our class properties, while in TypeScript we use `camelCase`.

Using this setup, we have found that the alias property (`Field(..., alias="***")`) is very helpful, combined with the `allow_population_by_field_name = True` property.

Simple model class example:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

class MyClass(BaseModel):
    my_property: str = Field(..., alias="myProperty")

    class Config:
        allow_population_by_field_name = True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_object = MyClass(my_property="banana")
```

The question is: Why doesn't Pylance understand that I want to be able to write `MyClass(my_property="banana")`? See screenshot from vscode below:

[image: Screenshot of error in VSCode]

Is there any way to configure Pylance/Pydantic/vscode to better understand this?

"Just living with" this is problematic because having red lines like this in our code promotes a mindset of "red is probably ok", so they lose their power.

---

### Edit May 8th, 2023:

We found a way to "circumvent" this problem, by creating a wrapper class, containing an `alias_generator`. It doesn't seem like pylance picks up on this, and therefore it acts as if it doesn't exist.

I'm sure using the system like this isn't something people do a lot, but this helped our team. Also it allows us to not write `= Field(..., alias="camelCase")` everywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like this is a known problem as you can see from issue [#4936](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/4936). It has to do with the way [`dataclass_transform`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.dataclass_transform) (from [PEP 681](https://peps.python.org/pep-0681/)) handles the `alias` field attribute.

There is currently no elegant solution for this, but there may be with Pydantic v2 at some point.

I agree that you should not just passively ignore the warnings. It is always better to *explicitly* ignore them, if you did everything you could to fix the underlying issue.

Therefore I propose this is a clear-cut use case for `# type: ignore` or more specifically `# pyright: ignore` as suggested [here in the documentation](https://docs.pydantic.dev/visual_studio_code/#disable-type-checks-in-a-line).

Sometimes you just hit the limits of the Python typing system. And when you do, explicit `ignore`-directives are the correct way to deal with that.

Comment: Ah, sad. I guess there won't be a "more correct" answer until an eventual v2 then. Thanks!